# Operations with large numbers

Tags: matlab, largenumber

I have some numbers a_i (for i=1 to 10000).
I need to compute exp(a_i)/sum(exp(a_j)) using matlab.

Of course, it is impossible to calculate straight away. I found some tricks, the most interesting [being](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/242167):

> "Suppose we want to find exp(7.0873e002). This will be a large number indeed but still just barely within matlab's capability of direct calculation. However, we can find the separate exponent and mantissa without calling on 'exp' as follows;

```
 a = 7.0873e2;
 x = a/log(10);
 D = floor(x); % D will be an integer
 F = 10^(x-D); % F will lie in 1 <= F < 10

Then D will be the power of ten and F the mantissa

 F = 6.27376373225551 % The mantissa
 D = 307 % The exponent (power of ten)

Compare that with the direct answer:

 exp(a) = 6.273763732256170e+307"
```

I tried something similar, but the result in may case is Inf:

```
 a = 7.0873e5;
 x = a/log(10);
 D = floor(x);
 F = 10^(x-D);

 exp(a) = Inf
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is in `F` and `D`. Because your `a` is much larger than the example `a` (i.e. `e5` vs `e2`) which they state is just barely within Matlab's range, yours must be well out of the range and thus becomes `inf`. But it doesn't matter because `D` and `F` hold your answer, you aren't supposed to be checkin g it against `exp(a)`, the example only calculates `exp(a)` to demonstrate the proof of concept. But the whole point of this code is to give you a way to find `exp` of giant numbers.

In your case you get

```
D =

      307797
```

and

```
F =

    3.374110424643062 % Use format long
```

thus your answer is `3.374110424643062e+307797`